# C# cannot equal '&' with entityframework data

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, equals

```
public int getPartijId(string naam)
    {
        Partij partij = null;

        try
        {
            partij = repository.Partij.Single<Partij>(p => p.naam.Equals(naam));
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {

        }

        return partij.partijID;
    }
```

I want to get a certain value (CD&V) out of our database, by comparing the name in the database with a linq statement but I'm getting a null value back...

With the rest of the values, this method works, but I suspect the problem is '&' in the name/string

Comment: Actually, the `.Single<T>` overload cannot return `NULL`. If no records (or multiple records) are found, if will throw an exception.

Comment: Can you show how you call this method, especially how you give the parameter `naam`  a value?

Comment: What is null? Partij or Partij.PartijID? And show us the values you compare, as well as the input and the record's name.

Comment: @Silvermind partij becomes null

Comment: @Maarten partijID = partijmapper.getPartijId("CD&V")

Comment: Remove the try/catch that is swallowing the exception. What does it say? (`Single` will also fail when there are *more than one* "partijen" with name "CD&V")

Comment: @Silvermind I'm trying to compare CD&V with CD&V, string from c# and string from database

Comment: You can try `partijID = partijmapper.getPartijId(@"CD&V");` (note the `@`), but at least **remove the empty try-catch**, this only makes it harder to see what is happening.

Comment: What is the repository that you are using? why dont you try to Profile and check what query is generated and just execute it on the database. See if you get any results out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try if your repository of Partij are all partijen

```
partij = repository.Partij.First(p => p.naam.Equals(naam));
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, same error. Is it the '&' in the string? or doesn't this make any difference?

Comment: Are there Partij objects in your repository.Partij?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only way your code can return null is if the `partijID` on the matched object is null.

Other options are throwing a null reference exception

```
Partij partij = null;

try
{
    // this may throw an exception because there may be more or less than one item matching your predicate
    partij = repository.Partij.Single<Partij>(p => p.naam.Equals(naam));
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // this is hiding that exception
}

// this will throw another null reference exception because the first call didn't actually set the partij variable
return partij.partijID;
```

P.S. It's almost never a good idea to catch an exception then completely ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

How is your table designed? Does the naam field have a unique constraint on it? Are you 100% sure you have exactly one row with a value of "CD&V" in the naam field? My guess would be you're getting multiple rows back and then swallow the exception, so partij stays null.

What's the exception message exactly?

Is partijID actually null in the database?

Comment: the problem is solved! In a way, he inserted the value CD&V wrong in the database, so when we read it, they value was CD&V\r\n ... I deleted the row and inserted it again, but it is fixed now, so thank all of you for your help :)